# How to keep Gnome Terminal from moving to another monitor?

Tags: gnome-terminal, multi-monitor

I have two 4k monitors side by side and multiple instances of Gnome Terminal with tabs in them positioned on the left and right halves of those monitors.
When I create a new tab inside one of the terminals with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, sometimes the terminal will switch monitors for example move from the left half of the right monitor to the right half of the left monitor. How can I stop this?

#### Versions

```
Linux archlinux 6.7.4-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon, 05 Feb 2024 22:07:49 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
GNOME Shell 45.4
x11
# GNOME Terminal 3.50.1 using VTE 0.74.2 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD
```

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that this probably happens when gnome-terminal initiates a window size change. To avoid that, make sure that you don't have profiles with different font sizes and you also avoid zooming in/out. Also enable to always show the tab bar, e.g. in `dconf-editor` by navigating to `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/tab-policy`.